# Issue with Incorrectly Concatenating/Manipulating Class Names in JavaScript Game

Tags: javascript

So I have been studying coding recently, specifically Javascript, I am currently making a project that is cloning the "Breaching Protocol" mini game of the game Cyberpunk 2077.
Here is my source code:
https://github.com/Icyretsz/Cyberpunk-2077-Breach-Mini-game-Clone
For anyone who don't know about it, the game is about the players click on hexes in a matrix of hexes, and certain sequences (there are 3 sequences) of hexes need to be matched. Each sequence is represented on the screen, and the hexes that players clicked in the matrix are compared to these sequences to determine if a sequence is complete or failed. Only a single hex can be chosen at a time. The selected hexes are stored into a *buffer*.
Here are the code sections where I think contain the source of the problem:

```
function coreMatrixMechanic() {
        //Creating the matrix
        let arrayOfAllHexadecimalsInSequencesArray = getArrayOfAllHexadecimalsInSequencesArray();
        matrixSize = getHexMatrixSize();
        for (let i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
            let row = document.createElement('div');
            matrixContainer.appendChild(row);
            let matrixOfHexadecimalsRows = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++) {
                let rowContents = document.createElement('button');
                row.appendChild(rowContents);
                let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayOfAllHexadecimalsInSequencesArray.length)
                rowContents.textContent = `${arrayOfAllHexadecimalsInSequencesArray[index].textContent}`;
                rowContents.className = `matrixBTN-${i}-${j}`;
                //handle hexadecimal buttons when chosen
                rowContents.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    bufferSlots[bufferIndexCount].textContent = rowContents.textContent;
                    chosenHexadecimalsContainer.push(rowContents);
                    flagChosenHex(); //flag chosen hex with `chosen-hexadecimals` class name
                    ...
                    sequence1IndexTracker = compareClickedHexadecimalsToSequence(sequence1IndexTracker, sequence1);
                    sequence2IndexTracker = compareClickedHexadecimalsToSequence(sequence2IndexTracker, sequence2);
                    sequence3IndexTracker = compareClickedHexadecimalsToSequence(sequence3IndexTracker, sequence3);
                    sequenceCheck(sequence1IndexTracker, sequence1);
                    sequenceCheck(sequence2IndexTracker, sequence2);
                    sequenceCheck(sequence3IndexTracker, sequence3);
                    bufferIndexCount++;
                    if (bufferIndexCount === bufferSlots.length) maxBufferExceeded();
                });
                matrixOfHexadecimalsRows.push(rowContents);
            }
            matrixOfAllHexadecimals.push(matrixOfHexadecimalsRows);
        }
        disableBTNExceptFirstRow();
    }
```

This function is where the matrix of hexes (which are buttons) are created. An event listener is added to each of the button. The event listener do these things:

- Add the selected hexes into the buffer.
- Flags the chosen hexes with a class name: `chosen-hexadecimals`
- Check if the chosen hexes match the hexes in the sequence. (compareClickedHexadecimalsToSequence, I set this function to be equal to sequence1IndexTracker since sequence1IndexTracker is incremented inside the function).
- Check if there are available hexes in the matrix to match with sequences. If there are none, mark the sequence with a class name.
- The buffer is an array of hexes that the player chosen, so I created bufferIndexCount to monitor the index position of the hexes that are chosen in the buffer. When a hex is chosen, the bufferIndexCount will be increment to store the next hex.
  -The `chosen-hexadecimals` buttons will be disabled for the rest of the game.

```
function compareClickedHexadecimalsToSequence(sequenceIndexTracker, sequence) {
        let hexInSequenceArray = getArrayOfHexesInSequence(sequence);
        if (sequence.classList.contains('failed')) return sequenceIndexTracker;
        if (sequenceIndexTracker < hexInSequenceArray.length) {
            if (chosenHexadecimalsContainer[bufferIndexCount].textContent === hexInSequenceArray[sequenceIndexTracker].textContent) {
                hexInSequenceArray[sequenceIndexTracker].className = `correctly-chosen-hex`;
                sequenceIndexTracker++;
            }
        }
        return sequenceIndexTracker;
    }
```

This function is to check if the hexes that the player chose in the matrix match the hexes in the sequences. If matched, mark the hexes in the sequences by adding class name: `correctly-chosen-hex`.
sequenceIndexTracker is to monitor the index position of the array of hexes that are in each sequence.

```
function sequenceCheck(sequenceIndexTracker, sequence) {
        if (sequence.classList.contains('failed')) return;

        let arrayOfHexadecimalsInASequence = getArrayOfHexesInSequence(sequence);

        for (let k = 0; k < arrayOfHexadecimalsInASequence.length; k++) {
            if (k === sequenceIndexTracker) {
                if (arrayOfHexadecimalsInASequence[k].classList.contains('correctly-chosen-hex')) {
                    return; // The currently clicked hex is correctly chosen, do not mark as failed
                }
            } else {
                let hexFound = false;
                for (let i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
                    for (let j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++) {
                        if (matrixOfAllHexadecimals[i][j].classList.contains('chosen-hexadecimals')) continue;
                        if (matrixOfAllHexadecimals[i][j].textContent === arrayOfHexadecimalsInASequence[k].textContent) {
                            hexFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (hexFound) break;
                }
                if (!hexFound) {
                    sequence.classList.add('failed');
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This function is to check if there are hexes left on the matrix that matches the un-selected hexes in the sequences. For example, I have a sequence A1 A2 A3, if there are no A1, A2, A3, either it is not generated in the matrix in the first place or the player chose it already which will be disabled it for the rest of the game, the function will ignore it when checking for matches

```
if (matrixOfAllHexadecimals[i][j].classList.contains('chosen-hexadecimals')) continue;
```

, in this case A2 will not registered as correctly chosen hex because at the time, A1 might not been chosen), then the sequence is not solvable, hence marked with a class name `failed`.

**The problem is:** for example: I have a sequence: 63 34, and the matrix only have a single 63, when I click on it, the sequence will immediately marked as failed even though 34 are available. This is because the compare function go first, it disabled the 63 button, and the check function go after, ignoring the disabled function. Since there are no 63's besides the disabled one, the function marked the sequence as failed. (the chosen hex marked as green, correct hex marked as bold yellow, the whole failed sequence section marked as red).
[image]

I did tried adding a line to check if the current hex in the sequence is marked with `correctly-chosen-hex`, the function will return from there but does not work. The other sequences may not have correct chosen hex yet so I have the undefined error.

```
function sequenceCheck(sequenceIndexTracker, sequence) {
        if (sequence.classList.contains('failed')) return;

        let arrayOfHexadecimalsInASequence = getArrayOfHexesInSequence(sequence);
//Add below line
        **if (arrayOfHexadecimalsInASequence[sequenceIndexTracker].classList.contains('correctly-chosen-hex')) return;**
        for (let k = 0; k < arrayOfHexadecimalsInASequence.length; k++) {
            if (k === sequenceIndexTracker) {
...
```

I wonder if there is a way to monitor changes of a the element's class name, so that when a button been added the class name `correctly-chosen-hex` at the time, the function would know and the stop executing further.

If you really have a time to look at my codes, I am really really appreciated. I am new to developing to my codes can be messy, any tips on names and positioning block of codes are also appreciated. If you need more information, please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: using `className` overwrites all classes with the passed value, but you say you want to add the class `correctly-chosen-hex`. If that is the case you need to use `classList.add('correctly-chosen-hex')`. see: [DOMTokenList: add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add)

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean... I added class name 'correctly-chosen-hex' in the compareClickedHexadecimalsToSequence function already. Actually I need some way to mark the changes made to class names so that when the only hex available been chosen, the checkSequence fuction wouldn't mark the sequence failed because when a hex is chosen in the matrix, the checkSequence wil ignore it. At least this is how I think to solve the issue.